# how to delete a list of items by ids and field using ReactiveCrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-webflux

I tried to do it like this, but it doesn't work

```
@Repository
public interface NotificationRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Notification, Long> {

    Mono<Void> deleteAllByIdAndIdentifier(Iterable<Long> id, String identifier);

}
```

In the method I specify -> `List<Long> ids` , DB - posgresql

I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot encode parameter of type java.util.ArrayList
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `In`

deleteAllById**In**AndIdentifier

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods